# TWRP accepting `adb` connections but no `fastboot` connections

Tags: twrp, fastboot

I can connect to TWRP (3.2.3-0) with `adb` but `fastboot devices` does not list any and `fastboot continue` (while my phone is booted into TWRP) only prints:

```
$ fastboot continue
< waiting for any device >
```

I can rule out a driver problem since I have used `fastboot` successfully with the same combination of phone, cable and PC.

Answer (score 1):

ADB and fastboot are two different protocols. **Android Debugging Bridge** works in ROM or in Recovery mode, when adbd (adb daemon) is running on phone.

**Fastboot** is one of the most commonly used Firmware Update Protocols. It works in **bootloader mode** which is also called **download mode** or emergency download mode (**EDL**) by some vendors. Some devices have both modes where EDL provides more primary access as compared to fastboot. Some OEM's use different tools for firmware flashing such as **ODIN**, **nvFlash**, **QPST/QFIL** etc.

Bootloader mode is usually accessible by rebooting in bootloader mode from recovery or ROM, or by pressing Vol+ key when device is booting. Similarly EDL is accessible using different combinations of Vol+, Vol- and Power key.

Bootloader is one of the very first pieces of software that is loaded in booting process. **GRUB** is the most common one used on Linux PCs. On Android embedded devices, the most commonly used bootloader by SOC vendors is **ABOOT**. To know further about bootloaders, boot process and what we can do in adb/fastboot mode, have a look at given links:

- [Boot Process: Android vs. Linux](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-boot-process-android-vs-linux-t3785254)
- [ADB & Fastboot](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/adb-fastboot-commands-bootloader-kernel-t3597181)

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about `fastboot`. It is not another `adb`. There is no fastboot server (in TWRP) which accepts connections. Rather it is a step/mode in the boot process of Android. Think of it as GRUB. You need to reboot your phone while the `fastboot` command is waiting for your device.